# Wordpress: Filter Posts Custom Field Value Based on URL Parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I added a custom 'checkbox' field to each of my post with the help of a plugin called [Advanced Custom Field](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). The field name is 'country' and according to the plugin author,

**Enter each choice on a new line.For more control, you may specify both a value and label like this:
red : Red
blue : Blue**

My own value and label go like this:

US: USA

FR: France

Now, I want to filter posts based on the 'country' field value. So when the URL is like this example.com?country=us, it should display all posts related to USA.

I added the below code to my functions.php but it's not working.

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

// do not modify queries in the admin
if( is_admin() ) {

    return $query;

}

if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type'] && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'post')) {

    // allow the url to alter the query
    if( isset($_GET['country']) ) {

        $query->set('meta_key', 'country');
        $query->set('meta_value', $_GET['country']);

    } 

}


// return
return $query;

}
```

I'm a noob when it comes to PHP. What am I doing wrong?

Updated:

When I first tried it, it didn't work at all. When I tried to login into my admin page. I got another error:

> Xdebug: Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression
>   (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in
>   \wp-content\themes\functions.php on line 14

The code on line 14 is

```
if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type'] && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'post'))
```

Comment: When you say its "not working", can you give more information? e.g. are you getting an error? Is it returning the wrong results, or no results at all?

Comment: When I first tried it.. it didn't work at all. When I tried to login into my admin page. I got another error:  Xdebug: Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in C:\wamp64\www\\wp-content\themes\functions.php on line 14. Output triggered in C:\wamp64\www\\wp-content\plugins\query-monitor\collectors\php_errors.php on line 164

And on line 14, this is the code there: if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type'] && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'post')) {

Comment: Did you get this solved or are you still having issues that you need help with?

Comment: Still having issues with it.

Comment: What are they? We can't help if we don't know! The problem was clearly stated in the error message so I'm very surprised you're still getting it if you fixed your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what and where the issue is...
You `Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression` in the line `if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type'] && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'post'))`

The code isn't working because the `if` statement in line 14 cannot be evaluate correctly.

`isset` takes a variable (or number of variables) as its parameter - you are passing it in the entire expression for your `if` statement, which is not allowed. You use `isset` to check if a variable is set and isn't NULL *before* you check what it is Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php.

You need to change line 14 of your code to the following:

```
if( 
    isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) // check if the post_type query var has a value
    &&                                     // AND if it does...
    $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'post'  // ... only then check if its == "post"
)
```

It can all be on the same line as in your example (as long as you remove the comments)... I've just split it out to highlight the different parts of the expression you are evaluating.